# How to track ASP.NET Webforms before Application_Start?

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, webforms

I'm working on a legacy application built on ASP.NET Webforms and .NET Framework 4.6.2.

The application's initial page is very slow to start on my local machine and I'm trying to troubleshoot it. I put a breakpoint on Global.asax Application_Start method, and it's taking quite some time even before the breakpoint is hit. I'd like to know how can I track exactly what happens before the Application_Start event (what calls are made, external libraries used, etc.), from the moment I make the first request to the server, so I can get a starting point to improve the performance. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Well, while in VS create (or open) some aspx page with JUST hello world on it. Does that page take a long time to load?

And to be fair, create a brand new blank asp.net webforms project, and find out if that project also is slow to load.

In other words, this just might mean your computer is slow.

When you hit f5, then:

The project code is compiled. Then a bunch of information is "copied", setup, then configured for IIS to launch. Then a WHOLE web server is launched (IIS express), then the web page is loaded, and then IIS processes that page, and then it is rendered.

In other words, a BOATLOAD of startup stuff occurs. Once that WHOLE big web server is spooled up, then and only then does your application start and all that jazz start.

If you can navigate to another page (say from the menu bar (assuming your application has one), and then BACK to that supposed page that loads slow? Does that page load slow the 2nd time you hit that page?

If that is the case, then your computer might be slow, starved for memory, or even starved for processing to start up the WHOLE system of stuff required to run that whole web server.

if once the page is displayed, and everything runs normal, then this is not a slow loading web page, but in fact a slow load WHOLE web site, and in actual use and production of the system, then it not really slow anymore is it?

So, say if your computer only has 8 gig, and say a low or slow laptop processor, then startup of all the "enormous" moving parts required to run a whole web server system might be the issue, and NOT that the page load is really slow.

And since the production system will not be re-loading from 100% scratch each time a whole web server system, then you may well not have a slow system, but only a slow "first time" startup.

So, do other web site projects based on .net framework, and asp.net pages start out slow?

And is this a asp.net web site, or is this a asp.net web site (application) project?

So, quite a bit of "hand stands" will occur on first run and load of the web site. So, this could be your computer, and not really that the web site is slow.

Having stated the above?

I have some found web site projects RATHER slow to load, and this is especially in the case of a asp.net web site application. (as opposed to web site's, which tend to load a WHOLE lot faster - about 1 second, and the other was taking about 18-23 seconds on my old laptop (it was starved for processing).

On a older laptop, I was seeing about 18-23 seconds delay after hitting f5. On my newer laptop, I have about 2, sometimes 3 seconds delay from the time I hit f5 in code or markup to see the results and web site running.

So, often IIS has to be loaded and started, maybe SQL server started, and even more bits and parts. All of these things can take a LONG time on your dev box, but on a production server, all of those things are running all the time.

So, it not clear if you have a very slow web site, slow loading "specific" web page, or you just talking about the overall slow loading time for "any" first page to display, and then after that, everything is fine? In other words, it is f5 to start things going is the slow point in time.

And you didn't even note how long of a delay and time here?

Are you talking about 5 seconds, or 50 seconds?

Right click on your task bar, task manager.

Here is me hitting f5 on my laptop. Note the 6 cores go 100% max speed and power during that startup.

I do know that on my laptop, when I hit f5, then all 6 cores (12 threads) jumps about about 2ghz to 4 ghz, and all 6 cores are pinned for those 2-3 seconds while that whole web server is created, configured, and THEN started, and then the page in question has to load.

So, here you can see that hitting f5, the web page "starts" almost instant, and then about 4 seconds more.

(the processor usage is somewhat high - part of that is due to running the screen capture for this screen shot).

[image]

So, as "soon" as I hit f5, you can see the processor jump above 20%. I count about < 1 second for the browser to appear. Then about 4 more seconds. And the above is a slower to load page. And as soon as the page displays, then you see the cpu drop down.

As noted, try creating a new asp.net web site "application". A web site, they tend to load < 1 second. In fact above is the "by far" slowest startup I have. Most are about 1-2 seconds from hitting f5.

A asp.net web site application? They take longer - the whole site has to be compiled each time, and the .dll's have to be created.

Sometimes, it simple things like some virtual folder mapped to a location that does not exist (so on startup, a non existing folder or path name can take some time to "time out".

so, how fast does a new test project (create a new asp.net web site application (create a application, not a web site). I find that web sites load fast - even on computers with limited hardware.

However, asp.net web "applications" tend to load a WHOLE lot slower. (and thus more ram, and more cpu, and more cpu cores makes a HUGE difference in startup times).

Performance is a real art form in our industry. But, a few more details such as do all "application" sites start slow on your dev box, or JUST this one, and by how much compared to other sites.

Often, a delay can be network connection to a database, and say little or nothing to do with startup, but some network delay in say connecting to sql server which may well be some kind of network connection.

So, all first pages slow, or just one page?

does a new asp.net web site application (application is important here - not just web site) also startup slow? (if yes, then this is not specific to your site, is it???).

And using task manager - do you see high cpu usage during that startup (f5), or is it low? (this then suggests network and connection delays - not cpu and memory and performance issues.

So, a lot more trouble shooting here is required, but then again, we have little idea as to what testing you done so far, such as testing another web site application on your computer - and does it have things like authentication and sql server logon's involved.

I mean, we can have some issues with a car that will not start. So, we don't just yet swap out the engine, re-do the fuel injection system, and then ONLY to find out we forgot to put in a new battery, and that was the issue all along.

So, do a few tests - get some base-lines of say a test site - use one of the templates that has the "default" bootstrap menu, master pages etc. How fast does that start? Since if that site ALSO starts slow, then attempts at troubleshooting the existing site will be in vain, since all sites load slow - not just the "one" site your working on.